# Reducer is of type never

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to create a reusable reducer like this:

```
export function createNamedWrapperReducer(
  reducerFunction: Reducer<State, Action>,
  reducerName: ReducerNames
) {
  return (state: State, action: Action) => {
    const { name } = action;
    const isInitializationCall = state === undefined;
    if (name !== reducerName && !isInitializationCall) return state;

    return reducerFunction(state, action);
  };
}
```

Here is how the reducer looks:

```
export const reducer: Reducer<State, Action> = (
  state = initialState,
  action
) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionType.REQUEST:
      return { ...state, status: { isLoading: true, error: "" } };
    case ActionType.SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        data: action.payload ? action.payload : null,
        status: { isLoading: false, error: "" },
      };
    case ActionType.FAILURE:
      return { ...state, status: { isLoading: false, error: action.payload } };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Inside rootReducer the types are showing as follows:
[image]

However, my reducers are of type `never` when looking at created store.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Not really on topic, but are you aware of the official Redux Toolkit? Switch..case reducers are not a part of modern Redux for over two years by now - and `createSlice` might be pretty close to what you want to create there. https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux

Comment: Where is the `never` type? Please provide more details